# NSD DNS Server error

Tags: domain-name-system

i installed NSD DNS on my server , i created nsd.conf and master zone in /etc/nsd3

when i want restart NSD by this command `/etc/init.d/nsd3 restart` 
 give me this error : `Restarting nsd3...                                                                         [1390940496] nsd[1396]: error: cannot chdir to '/etc/nsd': No such file or directory`

what's problem?

Comment: It sounds like `/etc/nsd`, presumably the location of NSD's configuration file(s), doesn't exist.

Comment: i don't know why , i create zone files and nsd.confg in /etc/nsd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a permission issue - what's the output from `ls -la /etc/nsd` ?
If there's an nsd user, you might need to do `chown nsd:nsd /etc/nsd`
Try restarting it and see if there are any messages in syslog `tail -25 /var/log/syslog`
Just noticed you said you created the files in /etc/nsd3; you could try symlinking it like this:
    `ln -s /etc/nsd3 /etc/nsd`
Or maybe you just need to edit /etc/init.d/nsd3 and change the path?